# grep one liner - extract two different lines from same file

Tags: bash, grep

I've a file containing many number of lines like following.

```
  == domain 1  score: 280.5 bits;  conditional E-value: 2.1e-87
                 TSEEETTCTTTGSG---BTTSSB-HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHSSS---B-HHHHHHHSTTTSTGCGBB-HHHHHHHHHHHTEBEBTTTS---SSCSESECTTGCGSCEBEESEEEEEESSBHHHHHHHHHHHSSEEEEEECTSHHHHTEESSEESCTSCETSS-EEEEEEEEEEEETTEEEEEEE-SBTTTSTBTTEEEEESSSSSGGGTTSSEEEE CS
  PF00112.18   2 pesvDwrekkgavtpvkdqgsCGsCWafsavgalegrlaiktkkklvslSeqelvdCskeenegCnGGlmenafeyikknggivtekdypYkakekgkCkkkkkkekvakikgygkvkenseealkkalakngPvsvaidaseedfqlYksGvyketecsktelnhavlivGygvengkkyWivkNsWgtdwgekGYiriargknnecgieseavyp 218
                 p+svD+r+k+ +vtpvk+qg+CGsCWafs+vgaleg+l+ kt +kl++lS q+lvdC + en+gC GG+m+naf+y++kn+gi++e+ ypY ++e ++C ++ + +  ak++gy++++e +e+alk+a+a++gPvsvaidas ++fq+Y++Gvy++++c++++lnhavl+vGyg ++g+k Wi+kNsWg++wg+kGYi +ar+knn cgi++ a++p
      1AU0:A   2 PDSVDYRKKG-YVTPVKNQGQCGSCWAFSSVGALEGQLKKKT-GKLLNLSPQNLVDCVS-ENDGCGGGYMTNAFQYVQKNRGIDSEDAYPYVGQE-ESCMYNPTGKA-AKCRGYREIPEGNEKALKRAVARVGPVSVAIDASLTSFQFYSKGVYYDESCNSDNLNHAVLAVGYGIQKGNKHWIIKNSWGENWGNKGYILMARNKNNACGIANLASFP 213
```

I just want to extract the line that is preceded by the PF and the associated line after it which starts with digit.

Here in this case, line that starts with PF is '`PF00112.18`' and line that starts with digit is '`1AU0:A`'. These ids will change for next domain, but `PF` is constant and its associated id starts with digit.

Here is what I've tried with `grep`, I hope there must be mistake in this oneliner. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
grep '^  PF \|      \d' inFile.txt
```

Expected output:

```
PF00112.18   2 pesvDwrekkgavtpvkdqgsCGsCWafsavgalegrlaiktkkklvslSeqelvdCskeenegCnGGlmenafeyikknggivtekdypYkakekgkCkkkkkkekvakikgygkvkenseealkkalakngPvsvaidaseedfqlYksGvyketecsktelnhavlivGygvengkkyWivkNsWgtdwgekGYiriargknnecgieseavyp 218

1AU0:A       2 PDSVDYRKKG-YVTPVKNQGQCGSCWAFSSVGALEGQLKKKT-GKLLNLSPQNLVDCVS-ENDGCGGGYMTNAFQYVQKNRGIDSEDAYPYVGQE-ESCMYNPTGKA-AKCRGYREIPEGNEKALKRAVARVGPVSVAIDASLTSFQFYSKGVYYDESCNSDNLNHAVLAVGYGIQKGNKHWIIKNSWGENWGNKGYILMARNKNNACGIANLASFP 213
```

Comment: And what is the result you get?

Comment: "I just want to extract the line that precede the PF".  I do not understand the presence of the phrase "that precede" in that sentence, as it does not seem that you want the line that precedes the line that matches PF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `grep` expression:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]\+PF\|^[[:space:]]\+[[:digit:]]' input.txt
```

The first pattern `^[[:space:]]\+PF` searches for a line which contains one or more spaces at the start, followed by the term `PF`. The second pattern also searches for a one ore more spaces at the start at the line, but followed by a digit.

This can be simplyfied to:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]\+\(PF\|[[:digit:]]\)' input.txt
```

since both patterns start with one or more spaces at the start of the line.

Let me finally suggest to use `egrep` instead of `grep` because extended POSIX regexes will save use some escaping:

```
egrep '^[[:space:]]+(PF|[[:digit:]])' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. If I know the exact number of spaces before PF and the associated ID, how should proceed?

Comment: `[[:space:]]\{3\}` for example if there are `3` spaces and `[[:space:]]{3}` if you are using `egrep`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include one more thing. The number of spaces are different for both. For ex. 2 spaces in front of PF and 6 spaces in front of associated ID

Comment: Then you need to modifiy the command on top of my answer. Insert `\{2\}` and `\{6\}` at the right places

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep "^[ \t]*(PF|[0-9]).*$" tmp_file
```

**[ \t]** is equivalent to a space. Its a tab delimiter.

So **^[ \t]*** grabs anything that starts with a space. The asterisk grabs all leading white space thereafter.

**(PF|[0-9]).*$** will grab the lines that start with either PF or a digit. The beauty of egrep is that you can specify multiple conditions encapsulated by parenthesis, separated by a pipe.

**.*$** grabs every from until the end of the line

so **(PF|[0-9]).*$** will grab everything that starts with PF or digits until the end of the line. It will not work without compensating for the leading white space first.

So we get :

```
egrep "^[ \t]*(PF|[0-9]).*$" tmp_file
```